# Pylons: __call__ and abort(), error code 500 instead of requested code

Tags: pylons

I'm trying to use pylons.controllers.utils.abort() function to terminate application and return corresponding code to the browser. But the only returning code is 500 Internal Server Error if calling from controller's method **call**(). For example

```
class ApiController(WSGIController):
    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        abort(411)
```

What should I change to get normal server response with code 411?

**Edit**: Nevermind, looks like `abort()` is not supposed to be used in the `__call__()` method.

Answer (score 0):

`abort()` is not working properly there so I'm using this code now:

```
return HTTPBadRequest()(environ, start_response)
```